# Azure AD application token generation in node js

Tags: node.js, azure

I have my application in Azure AD(SAML).I want to use that for token generation, validation and refresh token my rest API written in NodeJs. Can u suggest me library to implement that...I'm new to this SAML....

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

You can use msal to implement it.

```
npm install msal
```

Here provide a [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal) of msal for your reference.

Comment: thanks for the reply.... in msal generate token is there but what about validation and refresh token...